# BPMN; gateway with 2 condtions and 4 task output

Tags: bpmn

Im trying to model a proces where documents are being checked.

Its a sub proces where from a person some documents are checked wether it meets the requirements.

[image]

The person always has condition 1, and it could have condition 2 also.
So it always has to check document 1&2; when the person also has condition 2 document 3&4 are also checked.

So the outcome should be document 1&2 OR document 1&2&3&4 being checked.
Note: Each document could be individually rejected or approved.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How is this question related to bpmn.io or another software? If this is a sole bpmn related answer, this is not the right community to get a proper answer. Also please read the help me section on how to properly ask a question, see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Each condition should only have one outgoing edge. In your model it would also be possible that ony Condition 2 is executed. To execute two "check document" task based on the same condition I added parallel gateways infront of the two check tasks. This makes it more explicit that the check 1&2 respectively 3&4 tasks have to be executed together and e.g. just checking 1&3 is not possible. Condition 1 is always triggered by the parallel gateway while condition 2 is optional by garded by the exclusive gateway with the option to directly join to the parallel gateway or execute check 3&4.

[image: model]